# Comparing Keys in a Hashmap

Tags: java, csv, hashmap

I have a test.csv file that is formatted as:

```
Home,Owner,Lat,Long
5th Street,John,5.6765,-6.56464564
7th Street,Bob,7.75,-4.4534564
9th Street,Kyle,4.64,-9.566467364
10th Street,Jim,14.234,-2.5667564
```

I have a hashmap that reads a file that contains the same header contents such as the CSV, just a different format, with no accompanying data.

In example:

```
Map<Integer, String> container = new HashMap<>();
```

where,

Key, Value

```
[0][NULL]
[1][Owner]
[2][Lat]
[3][NULL]
```

I have also created a second hash map that:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("test.csv"));
CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
Boolean headerParsed = false;
CSVRecord headerRecord = null;
int i;
Map<String,String> value = new HashMap<>();
for (final CSVRecord record : parser) {
    if (!headerParsed = false) {
     headerRecord = record;
     headerParsed = true;
    }
    for (i =0; i< record.size(); i++) {
        value.put (headerRecord.get(0), record.get(0));
    }
}
```

I want to read and compare the hashmap, if the container map has a value that is in the value map, then I put that value in to a corresponding object.

example object

```
public DataSet (//args) {
    this.home
    this.owner
    this.lat
    this.longitude
}
```

I want to create a function where the data is set inside the object when the hashmaps are compared and when a value map key is equal to a contain map key, and the value is placed is set into the object. Something really simply that is efficient at handling the setting as well.

Please note:  I made the CSV header and the rows finite, in real life, the CSV could have x number of fields(Home,Owner,Lat,Long,houseType,houseColor, ect..), and a n number of values associated to those fields

Comment: First off, why does the 0th and the 3rd key in the Key, Value read NULL? Shouldn't they be Home and Long respectively? Secondly, I don't really get what you mean by "I have a hashmap that reads a file that contains the same header contents such as the CSV, just a different format, with no accompanying data."

Comment: No, because the text file only has those values, the spaces that Home and Long would be are empty, thus a null value. The sentence was me explaining that the values inside the text file were only Home, Owner, Lat, Long. Apologies if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Basically you have two hash maps (which are data structures, inside the program). The `value` map reads from the test.csv file and the `container` map reads from the empty file, am I right? But in that case, shouldn't the container one be empty? Since it's reading from an empty file?

Comment: And my last question, when you are comparing a hash map with data to one with no data (since it read from an empty file), how do you expect to find entries with similar keys? One of them doesn't have any entries (and hence keys) at all!

Comment: Alright wait, I finally get it. I'll explain it in the answer.

Comment: Let me provide some clarity. The text file contains just 4 lines, either the lines contains a Home,Owner,Lat,Long or the line is empty. The value map goes through the CSV file and store the first row, which is the header values- Home,Owner,Lat,Long. The container map read the text file and then we need to compare it to the value map and ask, hey does this textfile have a home, if it does cool, now give the value of the first home (5th Street) and pass that to an object

Comment: @RussianSoyuzRocket cool, looking forward to your answer and explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your approach to this problem is too unnecessarily long. From what I see, all you are trying to do is this:

Select a *two* columns from a CSV file, and add them to a data structure. I highlighted the word *two* because in a map, you have a key and a value. One column becomes the key, and the other becomes the value.

**What you should do instead:**

1. Import the names of columns you wish to add to the data structure into two strings. (You may read them from a file).
2. Iterate over the CSV file using the `CSVParser` class that you did.
3. Store the value corresponding to the first desired column in a string, repeat with the value corresponding to the second desired column, and push them both into a `DataSet` object, and push the `DataSet` object into a `List<DataSet>`.

**If you prefer to stick to your way of solving the problem:**

Basically, the empty file is supposed to hold just the headers (column names), and that's why you named the corresponding hash map `containers`. The second file is supposed to contain the values and hence you named the corresponding hash map `values`.

First off, where you say

```java
if (!headerParsed = false) {
    headerRecord = record;
    headerParsed = true;
}
```

you probably mean to say

```java
if (!headerParsed) {
    headerRecord = record;
    headerParsed = true;
}
```

and where you say

```java
for (i =0; i< record.size(); i++) {
    value.put(headerRecord.get(0), record.get(0));
}
```

you probably mean

```java
for (i =0; i< record.size(); i++) {
    value.put(headerRecord.get(i), record.get(i));
}
```

i.e. You iterate over one record and store the `value` corresponding to each `column`.

Now I haven't tried this code on my desktop, but since the for loop also iterates over Home and Longitude, I think it should create an error and you should add an extra check before calling `value.put` (i.e. `value.put("Home", "5th Street")` should create an error I suppose). Wrap it inside an `if` conditional and check of the `headerRecord(i)` even exists in the containers hash map.

```java
for (i =0; i< record.size(); i++) {
    if (container[headerRecord.get(i)] != NULL) {
        value.put(headerRecord.get(i), record.get(i));
    }
}
```

Now thing is, that the data structure itself depends on which values from the containers hash map you want to store. It could be Home and Lat, or Owner and Long. So we are stuck. How about you create a data structure like below:

```java
struct DataSet {
    string val1;
    string val2;
}
```

Also, note that this DataSet is only for storing ONE row. For storing information from multiple rows, you need to create a `Linked List` of `DataSet`.

Lastly, the container file contains ALL the column names. Not all these columns will be stored in the Data Set (i.e. You chose to NULL Home and Long. You could have chosen to NULL Owner and Lat), hence the header file is not what you need to make this decision.

If you think about it, just iterate over the values hash map and store the first value in string `val1` and the second value in `val2`.

```java
List<DataSet> myList;
DataSet row;

Iterator it = values.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();

    row.val1 = pair.getKey();
    row.val2 = pair.getValue();
    myList.add(row);
    it.remove();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer,  I was able to pick apart the pieces with your explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear! Sorry if I wasn't able to exactly answer it, or understand it.